# How can I make my dataLabel clickable on highmap?

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I want to get the point object on clicking the label as I want to zoom to that particular country

My dataLabel section is like this:

```
            dataLabels:{
              enabled:true,
              useHTML:true,
              format:'<div class="map-marker"><div class="map-yellow-marker">{point.count}</div><div>{point.countryName}</div></div>',
              color:'white',
              align:'center'
            }
```

Currently I have added an even listener on the  of label, but I can't get point object in this way

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide more complete code of your example, including the event listener? Thank you!

Comment: How about using build-in functinality, which on double click, zoom into region? http://jsfiddle.net/djdsfktt/ Solution works also on datalabels.

Comment: I want it on single-click @SebastianBochan